# Is possible to change pagination url names in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, pagination

Is possible to change pagination url names in cakephp?

For example:

```
example.com/tests/act/page:2/sort:title/direction:desc
```

to:

```
example.com/tests/act/pg:2/link:title/orderby:-date
```

Thank you all. But I am beginner in cakephp and pleased to see an example.

I read the documentation. but there is nothing about things I want.

Maybe I can translate those parameters and give to the Paginator class. but how?

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to just follow conventions and accept/embrace em instead of making your life more complicated. What is to gain here with your modification?..

Comment: Since the named-args used by pagination aren't configurable you can do what you've asked, but only by doing it yourself (also orderby isn't the equivalent of direction, so that's bespoke no matter what). I recommend you don't use named params at all =) and if you do need/want to do something like this you'll want to use a component to translate your-keys to conventional-keys, and your own helper to generate urls using your-keys

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use routing. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Just create a rewrite rule for it.

Comment: Thanks. but what kind of rewrite rule? Can you write me an example please?

Comment: I'm note sure that this is actually possible with routes, it would require named parameters to be renamed by the router, I've never seen such an option. I think he would have to rename the parameters manually from within in the controller. Though this might cause problems with reverse routing and stuff, so overall it's probably a pretty bad idea. @user2910460

Comment: -1 as this doesn't answer the question. An example route showing how to rename/proxy `/page:2` to `/pg:2` would answer the question though =).

Answer (score 0):

Pagination Works with named parameters, and there is not a simple way to rename them. You will need to modify the PaginatorComponent and PaginatorHelper to modify the parameters of the pagination.

Comment: How dear?! Is there a tutorial for modify those classes?

Comment: No that i'm aware of. You will need to dig into the CakePHP Source Code and modify those classes.

Comment: You can check the [Documentation on Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html), especially the Custom Query Pagination Section, you can override the paginate method on the Model.